# Create a new dictionary from 2 existing dictionory (1 nested dictionory , 1 dictionory of lists) python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries K and L. **K is a Dictionary of lists** and **L is a nested dictionary**

```
 K={
    'k1':[1,3,2],
    'k2':[3,4,5],
    'k3':[9,10,11]
    }

L = {
'l1':{'a':'1','b':'1','c':'2'},
'l2':{'a':'1','b':'3','c':'2'},
'l3':{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'2'},
'l4':{'a':'1','b':'4','c':'2'}
}
```

**What I need:**
I want to create a **new dictionary of lists** based on the below condition.

1. I need to check if **b values of L** are present in the K dictionary of the list or not.
2. If present I need to return a new dictionary with Key of K
   dictionary and Key of L dictionary.

For the above example, I need to return something like this

```
M = {'k1':[l1,l3,l2]
     'k2':[l2,l4]
     }
```

**Here is the code that I have tried:**

```
M= {}
for k, v in K.items():
  temp = []
  for i in v:
    if L[i]['b'] in K[k]:
      temp.append(i)
      M[k] = temp
    
print(M)
```

Comment: What's `k1`, `k2`, `k3` and what is `l1`, `l2`, `l3`?

Comment: Those are the keys of dictionory

Comment: So you should return `[1,2,3] as [l1,l2,l3]` ?

Comment: @Suman No. We need to compare those values with b values. and then return the corresponding key of L as the value in the new dictionary.

Comment: @Fusdev, just look my answer... simpler... try it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looking up the wrong thing in `L` here `L[I]`. I would do this by creating a lookup intially from `L`, that way you don't have to loop through L for every key in `K`. From there you can go through `K` once, looking up the items from the lookup.

Using `defaultdict` also allows you to handle the case where `L` has `b` values that are the same

```
from collections import defaultdict

b_val_to_l = defaultdict(set)
for lkey, ldict in L.items():
    # For each ldict, extract the 'b' value, convert to an int and add the
    # l key to the set of l values for the corresponding b value
    b_val_to_l[int(ldict['b'])].add(lkey)

print(b_val_to_l)

M = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in K.items():
  for i in v:
      # For each value in the k, get the set of corresponding l values
      b_set = b_val_to_l.get(i, set())

      # Add to the output dict
      M[k].extend(list(b_set))

print(M)
```

Comment: Just printing that so you can see what's happening. You can take it out

Comment: M is also a `defaultdict`, you can make it a normal `dict` by calling `dict(M)` if you need

Comment: `list_g = ['e','f','g','h']
for u in list_g:
  for lkey, ldict in L.items():
    # For each ldict, extract the 'b' value, convert to an int and add the
    # l key to the set of l values for the corresponding b value
    b_val_to_l[int(ldict[u])].add(lkey)` what is wrong in this code

Comment: `ldict` doesn't have the right key, e.g. `'e'`

Comment: Look up https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/. I can't help you with anything more though, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
new_dict, M = dict(), dict()

for key, val in L.items():
    new_dict[val['b']] = key

for key, val in K.items():
    for x in val:

        if str(x) in new_dict:
            tmp = new_dict[str(x)]
            lst = M[key] if key in M else list()
            lst.append(tmp)
            M[key] = lst
print(M)
```

## For the following K, L:

```
K = {
'k1':[1,3,2],
'k2':[3,4,5],
'k3':[9,10,11]
}

L = {
'l1':{'a':'1','b':'1','c':'2'},
'l2':{'a':'1','b':'3','c':'2'},
'l3':{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'2'},
'l4':{'a':'1','b':'4','c':'2'}
}
```

## Output M:

```
M = {
'k2': ['l2', 'l4'], 
'k1': ['l1', 'l2', 'l3']
}
```

[ Considered **b values of L** has a **unique** value, if not then you have to store it as a list in the `new_dict` dictionary.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. `L = {
'l1':{'a':'1','b':'1','e':'2'},
'l2':{'a':'1','b':'3','f':'2'},
'l3':{'a':'1','b':'2','g':'2'},
'l4':{'a':'1','b':'4','h':'2'} 
}`

Comment: is there any way to check different values like e,f,g,h by adding them to the list `new_dict[val['b']] = key`

Comment: Yes, you can add them to the `new_dict` BUT in that case, the `lst` may have duplicate values, So if you want unique values, just replace the `list` with `set`.

Comment: `list_g = ['e','f','g','h']
for u in list_g:
  for key, val in L.items():
    new_dict[val[u]] = key` what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
Mtemp = { k: [l for l in L
            if int(L[l]['b']) in K[k]
        ] for k in K }

# Mtemp can have None values, so let's remove them...
M = { k: l for k, l in Mtemp.items() if len(l) > 0 }
```

Output:

```
{'k1': ['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], 'k2': ['l2', 'l4']}
```